# Load the Qt platform plugin "windlows" in ""

Tags: c++, qt

I am running the executable file compiled using Qt+MSVC15. As i install the same .exe on another windows system it gives me following error.

```
"The application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "windows" in "".
```

**1st Attempt to solve it:**

Following is the structure of my folder structure:

```
-MyExecutable (containing example.exe)
 |_plugins 
   |_example1.dll
   |_platforms
     |_qwindows.dll
```

1.a As it was not able to find path to qwindows.dll. I created the folder platforms as shown in above picture and copied platform folder from "*C:/Qt/Qt5.6.1/Tools/QtCreator/bin/plugins/platforms/*" into it.

1.b I set Enviroment variable *QT_PLUGIN_PATH={path to folder containing executable}/plugins*

This setup runs my application however the others.dll are not included and hence a GUI with less features.

How can I make changes so that others.dll should also be linked/included in my GUI app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should copy your required dlls to a directory on the test computer. Then, you should add this directory to the system path.

I am using qt 5.5.

My dlls path :  C:\Qt\5.5\msvc2013\bin

In addition, you should create this path on the test computer:  C:\Qt\5.5\msvc2013\plugins\platforms

and you should copy qwindows.dll file to that directory.

Then, you should also add this path to the system path.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked my Qt project and it looks like:

```
-MyExecutable (containing example.exe) 
 example1.dll
 Qt5Core.dll
 Qt5Gui.dll
 Qt5Widgets.dll
 |- platforms
    qwindows.dll
```